# Is there a limited scopes approach to copy a sheet from a workbook not owned by the user into one they own?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

We have an Google Sheets Editor Add-on (Tiller Money Feeds) that uses limited scopes and we want to be able to efficiently and performantly insert template sheets stored in a spreadsheet we own into spreadsheets that users own using the add-on.

Example: a user is browsing available financial spreadsheet templates in our add-on sidebar while their spreadsheet is open. They find a solution for tracking their net worth and want to install it in their existing spreadsheet. We own the net worth solution. They own their spreadsheet. Our add-on doesn't have all drive permissions.

The provided example is really simple— just four lines of code— but it doesn’t appear to work with the spreadsheets.currentonly scope for a surprising reason… copying a sheet requires a source and a destination.

While the current/active spreadsheet can serve as one half of this pair (available with spreadsheets.currentonly), it does not appear possible to get a second Spreadsheet object without a broader scope like (all) spreadsheets. The example uses the openById() method, but this method— along with open(file) and openByUrl(url)— all use the spreadsheets scope.

Our desired workflow would look like this:

```
  var mastersSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(__ID__);
  var templateMaster = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(__NAME__)
  templateMaster.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet());
```

The issue is that we can’t seem to get either a mastersSpreadsheet or templateMaster object without an SpreadsheetApp open function (all of which use the broad spreadsheets scope).

Hence question: **is there an AppsScript method that can retrieve a non-active spreadsheet for use by the copyTo method using only the spreadsheets.currentonly scope?**

We would like to limit our public-facing add-on to the spreadsheets.currentonly scope, but are open to creating internal-use tools with broader scopes to archive data. We thought we had a promising lead with the Spreadsheet.getBlob() method. We were optimistic that we could archive  a spreadsheet as a blob using an internal-use tool and then in customer-facing scripts retrieve the spreadsheet “blob” using a fetch, rehydrate it into a Spreadsheet object, and then use the copyTo method. Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be methods to turn a Blob back into a Spreadsheet object.

Hence question: **is there an AppsScript method that can hydrate a Blob object into a Spreadsheet object for use by the `getSheetByName()` and `copyTo()` methods?**

Another approach we have explored is fetching `mastersSpreadsheet` with the Advanced Sheet Service/V4 API get() method using only the spreadsheets.readonly scope. Unfortunately the version of the copyTo method only exists with the broader spreadsheets scope.

Hence question: **is it possible to use the Advanced Sheet Service API to fetch a spreadsheet with the readonly scope and then convert that into an AppsScript Spreadsheet for use with its copyTo method (using the spreadsheets.currentonly scope)?**